# d3: force-directed graph with two CSVs

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm new to d3 and I'm getting a cryptic error that's keeping anything from being appended to the SVG element.

I'm trying to create a force-directed graph based on my own data, which is currently in two CSVs. Most of my code is copied from [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) example.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<html>
<head>
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width",width)
                .attr("height",height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

d3.csv("nodes.csv", function(node_error,node_data) {
 d3.csv("links.csv", function(link_error,link_data) {
   if (node_error) throw node_error;
   if (link_error) throw link_error;

        force
            .nodes(node_data)
            .links(link_data)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(link_data)
          .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", 2);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(node_data)
          .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("fill", "black")
            .call(force.drag);

        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return d.function_name; });

        force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

          node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
        });
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

nodes.csv

```
function_name,weight
calc_mandelbrot_vals,0
escapeval_to_color,0
get_mb_corename,0
extract_mb_filename,0
write_mb,0
read_mb,0
get_mb_path,0
write_array_file,0
read_array_file,0
get_mandelbrot,0
mb_to_png,0
mb_to_tkinter,0
main,0
println,0
randint,0
Image,0
ImageDraw,0
main_shuttle,0
```

links.csv

```
source,target,value
write_mb,write_array_file,1
write_mb,get_mb_path,1
write_mb,calc_mandelbrot_vals,1
read_mb,read_array_file,1
read_mb,get_mb_path,1
get_mb_path,get_mb_corename,1
get_mandelbrot,write_mb,1
get_mandelbrot,calc_mandelbrot_vals,1
get_mandelbrot,read_mb,1
get_mandelbrot,get_mb_path,1
mb_to_png,get_mandelbrot,1
mb_to_png,get_mb_corename,1
mb_to_png,escapeval_to_color,1
mb_to_png,println,1
mb_to_tkinter,get_mandelbrot,1
mb_to_tkinter,escapeval_to_color,1
mb_to_tkinter,println,1
main,mb_to_png,1
main,println,2
main,mb_to_tkinter,1
main_shuttle,main,1
```

Here's the error I'm getting, I haven't found anything on google...

> TypeError: e[i.source.index] is undefined

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use two CSVs because of this unnerving sentence from the force layout documentation:

> Unlike some of the other layout implementations which are stateless, the force layout keeps a reference to the associated nodes and links internally; thus, a given force layout instance can only be used with a single dataset.

But maybe the data is effectively being merged into one dataset... if this is the problem, do I need to convert my data to JSON?

Thanks for reading this long question!

Answer (score 0):

you need to queue the two files before loading.
In version 3 that might involve a separate js file queue.js. In version  you can use `d3.queue`:

```
d3.queue()
.defer(d3.csv, "nodelist.csv")
.defer(d3.csv, "edgelist.csv")
.await(function (error, file1, file2) {
createForceLayout(file1, file2);
});
```